# Geonode optimization and boolean operations

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm looking for tips on how to improve the performance of my geonodes. I found out the hard way that even if the geonode is not being displayed or not visible, they are still consuming resources. And it gets particularly noticeable when the geonode uses boolean operations on the geometry.

So, is there a... :

1. ... way to make an on/off switch so that when I'm not using that geonode (or not visible), I would expose an input node that would switch off the whole geonode  or at least portion of it that is causing the performance drop?
2. ... a node that is like the equivalent to committing or applying the geometry boolean operation so it doesn't perform it all the time?

Here's an example node, I wanted to have a switch that would disable the above nodes when I'm not viewing it. Hopefully, there's an automatic way of doing that but if not, at least a switch to effectively disable that part using a geometry input?
[image: sample node]

I've been searching the net about these but I'm not getting any results.

Comment: There is exactly that node if I understand the question correctly: the Switch node.  Also, I have used it for the purpose you are describing, to switch off a boolean operation so I can make some changes without it.

Comment: Thanks, goldfish, that also answers my question. There are just so many nodes that I missed it 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is e.g. don't instance elements with a switch:

[image]

[image]

or instance less...

[image]

[image]

to disable whole nodetree use separate geometry:

[image]

[image]

```
Note: i had contact to one of the developers of GN and he gave me the hint to not use the boolean mesh node because it is very slow and a bit buggy. So maybe you should use "delete geometry" node instead, if feasible.
```

Comment: Oh! Thanks for the heads up about using "delete geo" instead of boolean. That's really helpful advice, plus, it sounded like they might decide to ditch the boolean node. I'll try to digest the rest of your answer first. I'm pretty new to geonode stuff 

Comment: Well…if I see your node tree you cannot be that new….

Answer (score 0):

For more convenience, use a switch node combined with the *Is Viewport* boolean.

[image: node setup]

The input boolean (in my case *"Use Proxy"*) can be controlled via the modifier panel. By adding the *Is Viewport* it only triggers in the viewport. This is useful, if you don't want to reset every switch before rendering.